# What will be the last number of the set B in which a set B={$2$,$3$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$10$,_ ,_ ,_______} contain $300$ nos.

Tags: number-theory

> A set B={$2$,$3$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$10$,_ ,_ ,_______} contain $300$ nos. in which squares and cube of the no. are eliminated. then what will be the last number of the set B?

Our Approach:

As we have to eliminate
 $4$,$8$,$9$,$16$,$25$,$27$,$36$,$49$,$64$,$81$,$100$,$121$,$125$,$144$, $169$,$196$,$216$,$225$,$256$,$289$.

So total of $20$ nos will be eliminated.

So the req no will be the $320$th no strating from $2$.
Ans is $321$.

> Is there any other approach to solve this kind of problem?Correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Should $64$ be excluded?  It is a square and cube, but $4$ and $8$ have already been excluded so it is not a square or cube of a number in $B$.  I think the question is not clear, but that the intention is that it not be.  My answer would be $320$